# Create shipment programmatically and facing error

Tags: magento2, shipment

I am trying to create shipment programmatically. Following a tutorial, but facing error on save shipment.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
$orderId = 100002156;
$order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);

if (!$order->canShip()) {
    echo "Can't Ship";
    die;
}

$orderShipment = $this->_convertOrder->toShipment($order);

foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {

    if (!$orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
        continue;
    }

    $qty = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
    $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qty);

    $orderShipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
}

$orderShipment->register();
$orderShipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

$this->save();
$this->getOrder()->save();
```

Can anyone tell what is the issue?

Comment: what is the context of your code, in what class do you use this code? And what is the error on which save (`$this->save()` whatever object `$this` is or `$this->getOrder()->save();`?

Comment: I am using it in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This :-**

```
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface');



$incrementId = "000000165"; //Increment Id
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
        ->loadByAttribute('increment_id', $incrementId);

if ($order->canShip()) {

    $convertOrder = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
    $shipment = $convertOrder->toShipment($order);

    foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {

        if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
            continue;
        }
        $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();

        $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);

        $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
    }

    $shipment->register();
    $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

    try {
        // Save created shipment and order
        $shipment->save();
        $shipment->getOrder()->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
       echo "Shipment Not Created". $e->getMessage(); exit;
    }

    echo "Shipment Succesfully Generated for order: #".$incrementId;
} else {
    echo "Shipment Not Created Becuase It's already created or something went wrong";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak Rathod, will try this

Comment: Working Or Not ??? Most Welcome